# How reshape many colums to one

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hello I have dataset which contain many colums and 214 rows when I print data it looks like:

```
[[ 1.52101 13.64     4.49    ...  8.75     0.       0.     ]
 [ 1.51761 13.89     3.6     ...  7.83     0.       0.     ]
 [ 1.51618 13.53     3.55    ...  7.78     0.       0.     ]
 ...
 [ 1.52065 14.36     0.      ...  8.44     1.64     0.     ]
 [ 1.51651 14.38     0.      ...  8.48     1.57     0.     ]
 [ 1.51711 14.23     0.      ...  8.62     1.67     0.     ]]
```

Now I would like to reshape it but when I call:

```
X = X.reshape(214, 1)
```

I got

```
cannot reshape array of size 1926 into shape (214,1)
```

It is possible to reshape this to 214,1 ? I can't reshape it to 1926,1 or for example 214,9 I need 214,1. Maybe I don't prepare correct data
My full code

```
names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
dataset = pandas.read_csv('./glass.data', sep= ',', names = names)
Y = np.array(dataset['k'].values)
Y = Y.reshape(214, 1)
del dataset['k']
del dataset['a']
X = np.array(dataset.values)
print X
X = X.reshape(214, 1)
print X
```

Comment: Do you just want the first column? Do you want the first 214 values? Obviously that size array cannot fit into that shape, please review [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: What needs to be (214,1)?  One column of the dataset?  9 columns?  What is `X.shape`?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you have an array(X) with the size 1926, i.e. your array contains 1926 elements. Now you want to put 1926 elements in an array of shape (214,1) which has only room for 214 elements.

```
cannot reshape array of size 1926 into shape (214,1)
```

This is supposed to tell you that it is not possible to fit 1926 elements into an array with only 214 spots.

```
X = np.array(dataset.values)
```

This line might be your error. Do you really want to have all values from dataset to be stored in X? Or do you maybe only want the values from one column (say 'b') like you did it for Y (with 'k').

```
X = np.array(dataset['b'].values)
```